# How do I make a test case to fail using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am fairly new to Selenium and I have started off using selenium IDE. I have to test a login page. I have written test cases for the following:
1. Login Successful-(valid username and password)
2. Login Unsuccessful(all the combinations of empty username and passwords,incorrect username and passwords etc)

I have used assertions to test for the validity of a page. If I run the test suite, I do not get any failure.All the test cases run effortlessly. My manager wants me to write test cases for negative ones-unsuccessful login and these should fail so the user need not check the IDE for failure log. How do I achieve this?

How do I run the complete test suite with user not checking the IDe and gets to know that the test case fails?

Comment: Why would he need to know that a negative test failed "as intended"? -- Isn't that the okay scenario, just like all the positive tests?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any failures because you have specified what behavior should happen as a result of an incorrect username/password etc.

1- Enter correct username
2- Enter incorrect password
3- Click Login
4- Receive error of incorrect password

As far as your Selenium test is concerned the test is passing because you are receiving the password error as expected.
It sounds to me like your manager does not know what a 'negative test' is. A negative test is the unhappy scenario for instance where a user enters data incorrectly. From what I can see you have covered both happy and negative test scenarios for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty different in the cases but usually, when you have bad case, for example wrong email, username or password, you are expecting some text that will notify you for the mistake. So if you assert/verify that this text is shown, you practically cover the wrong case. So use `assertTextPresent` and type the expected string.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad of a question for SO. Your post may get closed.

First write out each of your tests as a manual test. How would you **manually** test that login failed? Then just automate those steps.